# devstack stack.sh fails because of pip package requirements

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, openstack, requirements.txt

I am trying to install OpenStack on `Ubuntu-server16.04` using `devstack`

I cloned the stable branch of *queens* and i have a simple `local.conf` file

when i try to run `stack.sh` it keeps printing the following warnings while doing some of the work

Ignoring EditorConfig: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment

```
Ignoring EditorConfig: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring argh: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring argh: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring blinker: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring blinker: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring brotlipy: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring brotlipy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring cssutils: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring cssutils: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring h2: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
```

And early on in the install it tells me that i will have an old package

```
glance-store 0.24.0 has requirement oslo.concurrency>=3.26.0, but you'll have oslo-concurrency 3.25.1 which is incompatible.
openstacksdk 0.14.0 has requirement keystoneauth1>=3.7.0, but you'll have keystoneauth1 3.4.0 which is incompatible.
oslo-vmware 2.30.0 has requirement oslo.concurrency>=3.26.0, but you'll have oslo-concurrency 3.25.1 which is incompatible.
```

And at some point it stops with the following error

```
Obtaining file:///opt/stack/glance
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 521, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.check_if_exists()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1036, in check_if_exists
    self.req.name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 432, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 968, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
ContextualVersionConflict: (oslo.concurrency 3.25.1 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('oslo.concurrency>=3.26.0'), set(['glance-store']))
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I tried to `pip install --upgrade oslo.concurrency` i got a newer version (3.27), but when i `./clean.sh; ./unstack.sh; ./stack.sh` i get the same error, i believe it deletes the 3.27 version and installs the older version back

any ideas how to solve this ?
thank you.

## UPDATE : adding local.conf

```
[[local|localrc]]

RECLONE=yes
# Enable heat services
enable_service h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw

# Enable heat plugin
enable_plugin heat https://github.com/openstack/heat
enable_plugin heat-dashboard https://github.com/openstack/heat-dashboard

# ceilometer and aodh for alaming
# CEILOMETER_BACKEND=mysql
enable_plugin ceilometer https://github.com/openstack/ceilometer
enable_plugin aodh https://github.com/openstack/aodh
enable_plugin zaqar https://github.com/openstack/zaqar
enable_plugin mistral https://github.com/openstack/mistral

# Ubuntu Image
IMAGE_URLS+=",http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/daily/xenial/current/xenial-minimal-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img"
IMAGE_URLS+=",http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img"


HOST_IP=10.11.200.110
SERVICE_HOST=10.11.200.110
MYSQL_HOST=10.11.200.110
RABBIT_HOST=10.11.200.110
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=10.11.200.110:9292
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=admin
RABBIT_PASSWORD=admin
SERVICE_PASSWORD=admin

IP_VERSION=4


# Open vSwitch provider networking configuration
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex
```

Comment: I would try to run `./stack.sh` until it fails, then update the package, and then run `./stack.sh` again without running `clean.sh` or `unstack.sh`. Got a similar error recently and this worked for me (after upgrading two packages)

Comment: thanks for the comment i tried that but still the same thing :(

Comment: Can you update the question with your `local.conf` just to double check, please?

Comment: @vabada updated

Comment: I tried with your `local.conf` and it works for me. Did you give it a try with a new fresh VM? In addition, which devstack version are you using? master?

Comment: i am using master and i did try with a fresh environment *i have Ubuntu-server-16.04 on bare metal* which distribution of Linux are you using **should i try with desktop version?**

Comment: I am using Ubuntu server 16.04 as well. To be more detailed, I got the `xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img` from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/ some 5-6 days ago.